# Is there a way to use AWS Data Pipeline for ETL project?

Tags: soap, amazon-web-services, ssis

I have a data transformation task at hand and am currently in need of implementing an SSIS class package using AWS Data Pipeline. Is it possible to do custom code using its SDK to retrieve data from third party SOAP based web services?

I obviously need to pull data from third party SOAP Service and then do a lot of data massaging of my own before I can dump that data on an Amazon S3 storage.

Any help in this direction is welcome.